# Замена %20 на + в url

Tags: php, javascript, html

Здравствуйте!
Есть форма поиска:

```
form id="search" name="search" method="get" onsubmit='document.location.href= "/search/"+q.value; return false;'>
```

При поиске адрес получается:

```
site.ru/search/юрий%20шатунов
```

а нужно:

```
site.ru/search/юрий+шатунов
```

как сделать это?

Comment: в q.value заменить все пробелы на плюсы

Comment: Понимаю офтоп но зачем?

Answer (score 1):

Просто замените все пробелы на плюсы с помощью функции `replace`

```
form id="search" name="search" method="get" onsubmit='document.location.href= "/search/"+q.value.replace(/\s/g, '+'); return false;'>
```

Comment: Попробывал так:onsubmit='
document.
location.
href= "/
search/"+q
.value.
replace(/
\s/g, '+');

но так не работает location

Comment: Не уверен конечно, но похоже это из-за лишних пробелов, если Вы конечно не дописали их самостоятельно в комментариях, а вообще можно сократить запись: `onsubmit='location = "/search/"+q.value.replace(/\s/g, '+');`

Comment: Кавычк внутри replace должны быть двойные!

Сбасибо за помошь!

Comment: Точно! Это из-за того что `onsubmit` взят в одинарные, пропустил этот момент :)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте функцию `decodeURI(str)` в JS.
Используйте функцию `urldecode($str)` в PHP.